# How to make customizable sized square grid of buttons? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin

Does anybody have any idea of how to make a customizable sized square grid of buttons? I want to make it so I can change the size of the array of buttons on the square. I have been trying to somehow make a list view within a list view but that does not seem to be working. Does anyone have another way to go about this problem?
[What I want to do but with custom size since right now I just used 5 different list views, one for each column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2MOv.jpg)

Below is what I have tried so far with a list view within a list view

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" Rotation="270">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout>
                                        <Button BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" CornerRadius="5" WidthRequest="38" HeightRequest="38" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you have tried and the result you want to get for us?

Comment: Why not use a Grid control?

Comment: Ok I just posted the code for what I've tried so far and a screenshot of the button grid I want custom sized.

Comment: Jason are you talking about Xamarin Data Grid Control FlexGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jason said, you could use grid instead of listview.

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button
            x:Name="btn1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn2"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn3"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn4"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn5"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn6"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn7"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn8"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn9"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn10"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn11"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn12"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn13"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn14"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn15"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn16"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn17"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn18"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn19"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn20"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn21"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn22"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn23"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn24"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="3"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />
        <Button
            x:Name="btn25"
            Grid.Row="4"
            Grid.Column="4"
            HeightRequest="{Binding Width, Source={x:Reference btn1}}" />

        <Grid />
    </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see, thanks, that might work! The problem is I want the grid dimensions of row x columns to automatically change based on a user's action. So for example, the grid might be a 2x2 of equally sized buttons but can change to a 5x5 of equally sized buttons if that makes sense.

Comment: We could not do that. The count of the columns has been decleared before you add the buttons in grid.

Comment: Oh I see, that's too bad. Yeah that is why I was trying to use a list view but I guess that does not work either, thanks for helping though!

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any questions, please fell free to let us know.

Comment: Any update for this case? If this reply helps you, do not forget to accept as answer. Thanks~

Comment: Sorry for not following up, just marked as accepted!